# Can not change textbox value on autocomplete select

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, autocomplete

I want to change the textbox value on another textbox selection with autocomplete.  I'm using django 1.7 and jquery 1.9

I am not good at javascript I tried alot of solutions to make autocomplete work with django but I can not change the other textbox value.

This is django code

**view.by**

```
  def auto_complete(request):
   search = request.GET['term']
   products = Products.objects.all().filter(product_name__startswith=search)
   products_serialized = serializers.serialize('json', products)
   return JsonResponse(products_serialized, safe=False)
```

**url.by**

```
url(r'^autocomplete/$', views.auto_complete, name='Auto Complete'),
```

**textbox**

```
<input type="text" id="product" name="product" class="product" value="">
<input type="text" id="price" name="product" class="price" value="">
```

**javascript function**

```
    function Complete(){
    $( "#product" ).autocomplete({
        select: function (e, ui) {
            $("#product").val(ui.item.label);
            return false;
        },
        minLength: 1,
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/autocomplete',
                data: request,
                success: function (data) {
                    var ParsedObject = $.parseJSON(data);
                    response($.map(ParsedObject, function (item) {
                        var results = item.fields.product_name ;
                        return {
                            value: results
                        };
                    }));
            },
        });
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Does autocomplete work? Can you see suggestions? Try $(event.target).val(ui.item.value);

Comment: yes autocomplete works fine and when i select a choise "product" value changed successfully but i need to change "price" value also on "product" choise select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer

```
function Complete(){
$( "#product" ).autocomplete({
        select: function (e, ui) {
            $("#product").val(ui.item.label);
            return false;
        },
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/autocomplete',
                data: request,
                success: function (data) {
                    var ParsedObject = $.parseJSON(data);
                    response($.map(ParsedObject, function (item) {
                        var name = item.fields.product_name ;
                        var price = item.fields.product_price ;
                        var count = item.fields.product_count ;
                        var the_id = item.pk ;
                        return {
                            value: name,
                            price: price,
                            count: count,
                            the_id: the_id,
                        };
                    }));
            }
    });
},
    minLength: 1,
    autoFocus: true,
        select: function ( event, ui ) {
              $('#price').val( ui.item.price );
              $('#count').val( ui.item.count );
              $('#the_id').val( ui.item.the_id );
        },
    });
```